# How to broadcast in a wifi network of Android phones

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, android-wifi

I have a network of android phones, in which one of the phone acts as server. I try to do  a broadcast using the destination IP as `'255.255.255.255.'`. But it fails to send message. I give the logcat below. The server IP is `192.168.43.1`. I have also tried with `'192.168.43.255'`. But it too ended up in vain. For code, I had referred http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

```
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698): java.net.UnknownHostException: /192.168.43.255
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698):  at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:325)
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698):  at project.android.aec.ConnectActivity$ClientThread.run(ConnectActivity.java:139)
05-30 20:17:40.970: E/ClientActivity(698):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

The following is the code used to get broadcast IP

```
   private InetAddress getBroadcastAddress() throws IOException {
        mWifi= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        DhcpInfo dhcp = mWifi.getDhcpInfo();
        if (dhcp == null) {
          Log.d("BCast Address Fetch", "Could not get dhcp info");
          return null;
        }

        int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
        byte[] quads = new byte[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
          quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
        }
```

Comment: Netmask is 255.255.255.0.
I have edited the question to add the code used to find broadcast address. In my case, it is 192.168.43.255

Answer (score 2):

This is what  I use to get the Broadcast Addresses

```
for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
 NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
 for (InterfaceAddress address : intf.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
   System.out.println(address.getBroadcast().toString().substring(1));;
 }
}
```

The code in the reference link is a simple TCP Server/Client. It would be better if you post the code which you use to do the UDP BroadCast.